# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on NodeJs ,AngularJs Web Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

when i run my web application i get this error.this was happened suddenly.my application is MEAN stack appllication whicj has a end to end connection through APIs.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (D:
```

this is an API that is being exposed.

```
app.post('/api/filesReadUpload', function(req, res) {

    var eventReadUpload=new filesReadUpload({
      //id:req.body.id,
        dat:req.body.dat,
        details:req.body.details,
        tim:req.body.tim,
      //  space:req.body.space

    });

    eventReadUpload.save(function(err) {
      if (err)
          res.send(err);

      res.json({ message: 'Read file!' });
});
        });
```

[image]

can anyone support with this.if this information is not enough please inform me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` appears because the server is down. The reason why the server is down is because of the error you pointed:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

That means you tried to send the response twice. In case of error you have to run `return res.send(err)` because you want to not call the `res.json` in case of error. If you do (what currently is happening), you will get that error.

```
eventReadUpload.save(function(err) {
  if (err)
    return res.send(err);

  res.json({
    message: 'Read file!'
  });
});
```

You will have to figure out why the saving fails, but this will fix the initial problem.

Comment: error solved.Thank you very much.As u told have to find why the saving is not working.if you have any suggestion please let me know..

Comment: @Shan Ask a new question for that and mention what the error is.